# How can I run Windows 1.0 on a Windows 8 PC?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine

I'm certain this will require a Virtual machine, but I am not sure how to implement it or even if it is free to do.

I am currently running Windows 8.1 on an x64 based system

Comment: Will a browser-based version suffice?  http://thenextweb.com/shareables/2013/10/28/nostalgic-old-school-computing-website-runs-windows-1-01-browser/

Answer (score -1):

You have some virtual machines that are free to use (with limitations), like [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/workstation-evaluation), [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), some others are free and open source like [Qemu](http://www.qemu.org/).

I found a link to download a [Windows 1 image for VMware](http://thepiratebay.se/torrent/6875678/Windows_1.0_for_VMware), but downloading this could very possibly be illegal if Microsoft didn't give away their old OS (if that's what you meant by asking if it would be free to do).

Comment: I can't access thepiratebay from my Internet

Comment: Checking files for viruses was absolutely not my responsibility but yours. That kind of ungratefulness is actually what will stop well meaning people from wanting to help you in the first place.

There are other torrents for the same kind of file, other torrent sites than thepiratebay, you have a lot of choices. Use google.

Comment: Use malwarebytes to get rid of whatever virus you've installed. It's known to be quite effective. Then download something safer and run on any virtual machine you like.

Comment: Sorry I overreacted. Do you know where I can get other versions of Windows? Like 2.0 and 3.0 and 95 etc.?

Comment: I don't really know that. But i think only MS-DOS is free to use and open source now. So i'd go with torrents again to find copies of those systems.

Comment: MS-DOS is open source? Really? I thought Microsoft kept everything closed

Comment: It's been open source since very recently only.

Comment: So will they open-source Windows 1.0 in a few years

Comment: I have absolutely no idea (since i'm not them and i don't make their strategy) but it could be in their best interest open-sourcing even the most recent versions of windows (the google way), just to let devs "play" with it a bit more.